# How to solve problem with input user to mysql in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a problem with user input from java code to my mySQL database. Database looks like this:[image]

52 is a weight category next one is 62, 70 etc. But, user can input his weight and his lifted weight freely. So, query must approx. his weight to category and his lifted record to level class (Novice...).
For example User weight: 53 kG and his lift is 58 kilograms which makes him at UNTRAINED level and that's what i wan to to print out:
Here is what I wrote and it's not working:

```
  SELECT * ABS(lifted_weight-"+competitor.bench+" ) AS weight 
FROM benchpress WHERE body_weight= ABS(body_weight-$"+competitor.BodyWeight+" ) 
ORDER BY weight LIMIT=1"
```

Method in java works fine but I have problem with this query.

**EDIT**
here is error call

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: (conn=869) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'ABS(lifted_weight-$54 ) AS weight FROM benchpress WHERE body_weight= ABS(body...' at line 1
```

this 54 to input lifted weight

Comment: What problem do you have? Do you get error? If so, please provide error message you get.

Comment: Kindly provide an error message and also your query is not written in an efficient way

Comment: Um, `SELECT * ABS(etc...)` is definitely bad SQL syntax.

Comment: I will get you errors in couple hours but i don't know how to reach out to you.

Comment: Syed, could you elaborate on more efficient way to write this?